# Convertir UNIX TIMESTAMP to DATE en Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

Necesito convertir un unix timestamp que se almacena en una columna de tipo de datos VARCHAR2 a un tipo de datos DATE.

**Ejemplo..
1404316382  = 2014-07-02 15:53:02.000**

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, la dejo por si alguien más le sirve para resolver el mismo problema.

Para hacer la conversión se necesita de la siguiente instrucción:

```
to_char(to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval('1404316382','SECOND'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo otra opción que tambien te puede servir

```
SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + 1404316382  / 86400,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from dual
```